# Checking if Makefile exists before executing autocmd

Tags: command-line, autocmd, external-command, filesystem, statusline

I want Vim to execute build the project automatically after I write the buffer to a `*.c` or `*.cpp` file. Here is what I've done:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.c,*.cpp make
```

This one works as expected (but the output is noisy; see the bonus question below):

```
"main.c" 26L, 448C written
:!make  2>&1| tee /var/folders/x0/lrg8j6r535n4lvnfnj6lr2fr0000gn/T/vF0bk92/0
clang -g main.c
               (1 of 1): clang -g main.c
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

The problem is, when there is no makefiles in the current directory, an error is thrown:

```
"test.c" [New] 0L, 0C written
:!make  2>&1| tee /var/folders/x0/lrg8j6r535n4lvnfnj6lr2fr0000gn/T/vtVN9SA/0
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
(1 of 1): make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I tell autocmd to check if a makefile exists before executing the command?

**Bonus question**: can I tell autocmd to execute the command *quietly*? That is, don't show the output of the command, or more preferably, show it in the status line.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098521/vimscript-how-to-detect-if-specific-file-exists

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `filereadable()` is how we could detect whether a file exists. Here, you'd want to check `filereadable(expand('<amatch>:p:h').'/Makefile'))`.

In order to check for a `Makefile` in a directory above the one where your file is, it's `findfile()` you're looking for.

But beware if you have a lot of files, you won't want to freeze vim every time you save a file among the hundred if not the thousand a project contains. And if you want to do that in the background, you'll have to make sure to not start `make` several times in parallel.

Also, I don't know if you're aware of it, but single file projects don't need a `Makefile`. If you're using gnu-make, and if your version of gnu make is properly configured (Mingw one is the only one I'm aware of to be improperly configured), you can just execute `:make %<` to compile the current file into an executable.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out: it should be `filereadable` instead of `filereadble` or `filereadeable ` :)

Comment: Oups. Sorry :) I fix my message.